# Change bundle id of app that was used on TestFlight but not App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, bundle-identifier

I have an app that has been uploaded to itunesconnect and used for TestFlight.  I have uploaded many builds.

I now wish to upload the app to a different iTunes account.  However I can't because the name and bundleID are being used by the older version which is on TestFlight.

I need to either change the bundle ID on the older version that is on test flight or to transfer the app.  Unfortunately I can do neither.  There is no option or ability to change the bundle Id on the old version that is presently being used in TestFlight.  And there is no option to transfer the app as it has not been approved and not on store.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: try contacting Apple Support and provide them with all the required reasons for this change.

Comment: I just sent them a message.  Hope to receive a positive reply

Comment: let hope for the best!

Comment: @alionthego did you find any solution? I have the exact issue now. The only solution comes to my mind is to delete the TestFlight and then upload a new one, but I am afraid of the risks (I've contacted Apple support but no answer).

Comment: I ended up launching the app and then immediately after it was on the store in general release you have the option to transfer it to another account. Couldn’t find any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle id is register for development team so with same bundle id but different development team you can not release app. However, you can slightly twig your bundle id and app name, this way you can easily up the app.